# How to use an IF statement in conjunction with an UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could somebody please tell me the correct syntax for the following MYSQL query:

```
IF (order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '') WHERE order_id = '$id') THEN

        UPDATE orders
        SET order_product_id_1='$product_id', order_title_1='$order_title', order_size_1='$size', order_quantity_1= 1
        WHERE order_id = '$id'

        ELSE

        UPDATE orders
        SET order_product_id_2='$product_id', order_title_2='$order_title', order_size_2='$size', order_quantity_2= 1
        WHERE order_id = '$id'

        END IF";
```

I want the IF statement to check whether order_title_1 is NULL or empty across a specific row matching the order_id. If the column is empty then perform the UPDATE statement below, however, if the column IS NOT NULL or empty then carry out the secondary UPDATE statement following ELSE.

Thanks.

---UPDATE---

I've realised that my logic was incorrect for my query.

In pseudo-code, I'm trying to add details to a product box according to whether the box is empty or not.

So the first time a product is scanned - it will place the product in the first slot, and the second time a product is scanned it will place it in the second slot and the third time a product is scanned it will add it to the third unoccupied slot and so on. At the moment when the first product is scanned, the details are placed into all unoccupied slots. As each new product is the scanned the unoccupied slots below are all replaced with the new product details.

I need a way to separate each query so that the product details are added sequentially to the next unoccupied slot if the previous slot is occupied. I could create a separate scanning function for each product box but thought I might be able to combine them with some form of IF/ELSE statement.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Thanks,

Comment: as tagged PHP, why don't you do that in PHP?

Comment: @RoyalBg - How do you mean?

Comment: `if ($row['order_title'] == '') { $db->query("UPDATE...."); }`

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```sql
UPDATE orders
SET    order_product_id_1 = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', '$product_id'     , order_product_id_1),
       order_title_1      = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', '$order_title'    , order_title_1     ),
       order_size_1       = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', '$size'           , order_size_1      ),
       order_quantity_1   = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', 1                 , order_quantity_1  ),
       order_product_id_2 = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', order_product_id_2, '$product_id'     ),
       order_title_2      = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', order_title_2     , '$order_title'    ),
       order_size_2       = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', order_size_2      , '$size'           ),
       order_quantity_2   = IF(order_title_1 IS NULL OR order_title_1 = '', order_quantity_2  , 1                 )
WHERE  order_id = '$id'
```

However, this schema appears to be denormalised and might benefit from separating such item details into a separate table that references the order to which they belong.

Comment: Thanks - however, this seems to be adding the product into both of the separate orders i.e.. order_title_1 and order_title_2 when order_title_1 is null. It does overwrite order_title_2 if the product is scanned again with a new product.